# Select query in spring hibernate in spring mvc

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jsp, jakarta-ee

Hi i am writing an spring mvc, employee application using mysql database,hibernate annotations and jsp . The database contains one table **"Empdata"** where empid is primary key.And there is a column **"team"** in **"Empdata**".I want to select employees in a specific team, example all the details of employees in **"Team1"**.Here i can perform delete and edit operations in the application. For delete operation i am using

> sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("DELETE FROM Resource WHERE empid=" +resource.getEmpId()).executeUpdate();

query.I know the command line query for select is

> SELECT * FROM  EmpData WHERE EMPLTEAM ="Team1"

I want to know how to convert this query into hibernate?

please help,thanks in advance..

Comment: Check for Hibernate Query Language

Answer (score 2):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Resource where emplteam = :team");
query.setParameter("team", "Team1");
List list = query.list();
```

`emplteam` should be the property of your class Resource , not your database column's name.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is simple using HQL .

```
String hql = "FROM Resource E WHERE E.emplteam = team1";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Hope this helps

<sub>Note: Keywords like SELECT , FROM and WHERE etc. are not case sensitive but properties like table and column names are case sensitive in HQL.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using criteria api?

```
Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
   .createCriteria(EmpData.class).add(Restrictions.eq("EMPLTEAM", "teamxxx");

List<EmpData> result = crit.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Student where name=:name");
query.setParameter("name", "Raj");
```

In your case i guess the Entity name is Empdata(The object that represent the table)
And the field in the object is team(That has getter and setter in object)

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Empdata where team=:teamParam");
query.setParameter("teamParam", "team1");
```